# Elasticsearch: Aggregation on filtered nested objects to find unique values

Tags: elasticsearch, search, full-text-search, elasticsearch-5

I have an array of objects (tags) in each document in Elasticsearch 5:

```
{
    "tags": [
        { "key": "tag1", "value": "val1" },
        { "key": "tag2", "value": "val2" },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Now I want to find unique tag values for a certain tag key. Something similiar to this SQL query:

`SELECT DISTINCT(tags.value) FROM tags WHERE tags.key='some-key'`

I have came to this DSL so far:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "my_tags": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "tags"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "filter" : { "terms": { "tags.key": "tag1" } },
                "aggs": {
                    "my_tags_values": {
                        "terms" : {
                            "field" : "tags.value",
                            "size": 9999
                         }
                    }                   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But It is showing me this error:

`[terms] unknown field [tags.key], parser not found`.

Is this the right approach to solve the problem? Thanks for your help.

**Note:** I have declared the `tags` field as a nested field in my mapping.

Comment: Most probably, your `tags` field is not declared `nested` in your mapping type. Might that be?

Comment: @Val No :) It is declared as nested. I will update the question.

Comment: Can you use `term` instead of `terms` or put `"tag1"` inside an array, i.e. `["tag1"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mixed up things there. You wanted probably to add a `filter` aggregation, but you didn't give it any name:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "my_tags": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "tags"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "my_filter": {
          "filter": {
            "terms": {
              "tags.key": [
                "tag1"
              ]
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "my_tags_values": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "tags.value",
                "size": 9999
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, I know you tried this because you added (and deleted afterwards) a comment hours ago :-). Did you make it work in the end?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Bool Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/query-dsl-bool-query.html) inside the Filter-Aggregation:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "my_tags": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "tags"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "filter": {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "tags.key": "tag1"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "aggs": {
            "my_tags_values": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "tags.value",
                "size": 0
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

BTW: if you want to retrieve all buckets, you can write `0` instead of `9999` in aggregation size.

Comment: Be careful with retrieving all buckets ;-). Depending on how many they are, the nodes could end up using a lot of memory and get into memory pressure.

Comment: @AndreiStefan agreed. But I assuming he wrote `9999` because he want them all and the average is a few hundreds.