# Elasticsearch - How to aggregate count for specific type

Tags: elasticsearch

i have below json
JDisc is nested property within a document and 1 document can contain many JDisc

```
   Document{  
   Proprety:"somevalue",
   JDiscs:[  
      {  
         color:blue,
         categoryId:1
      },
      JDisc      {  
         color:red,
         categoryid:2
      }
   }
]
```

so my queries use nested path queries and check if JDisc is of specific categoryid. for say if it is 2.
I want aggregation result to be returned as "red":1 for color.
For a selected document, it gives me all JDisc Aggregation.
FYI, i have used Aggregation with Nested Path and still result is not what i expected.

Comment: Can you show your query, please?

Comment: You mat have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48153061/elasticsearch-aggregation-on-filtered-nested-objects-to-find-unique-values/48163835#48163835)